# [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Tags: ios, imageview

Share image in `uitableviewcell` button click event to share image in uitableview imageview image share

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{

CustomTableViewCell *clickedCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [Mytableview indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

int selectedIndexPath = clickedButtonIndexPath.row;
NSLog(@"SelectedIndexPath: %d",selectedIndexPath);
UIImageView * imageshow;
UIImage* imge = [[arry objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath]valueForKey:@"post_image"];
NSLog(@"imahe : = %@",imge);
imageshow.image = imge;
 NSString *textToShare = @"Vocabmeme image";
    UIImage *imageToShare = imageshow.image;
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[textToShare,imageToShare];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; //or whichever you don't need
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Plz Solve this error..........

Comment: okkk it try it bro ...

Comment: whats your problem?  i can't understand.

Comment: Post your question proper way to better to understand other developer. @Bhargav.